# Can't see animation after exporting to video

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, export, uv-image-editor

[image]

I started using Blender a few days ago...

For some reason, after I rendered the animation to a video file, I was left with this grid (see screenshot). **How do I go back to the *3D Viewport* where I can edit the animation?** The wierd thing is that I can see the camera's perspective just fine in the upper right. (I'm using Blender 2.77a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hover your cursor over the grid and key <kbd>Esc</kbd> until the grid goes away (probably twice).

What has happened is that because you selected *Image Editor* in the *Properties panel > Render tab > Render dropdown*, your computer rendered your video by switching the screen that was previously there (a *3D Viewport*) to a *UV/Image Editor*.

I generally select *New Window*, because then you can simply X out of the window once it is done.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I spent nearly 30 minutes trying to figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: @0-60FPS glad to help!